# General SSLEngine error with WSO2 AS and AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2, certificate, aws-api-gateway, application-server

here is our system configuration:
- a EC2 instance with the WSO2 Application Server (AS) 5.2.1 up and running
- our web service deployed on the AS

We want to use the AWS API Gateway service to intercept any request to our web service deployed on the Application Server.
However, we are experiencing several problems since we don't know how to configure the AS in order to authenticate the API Gateway service.
In this way, the AS acting as the backend can control and accept only requests originating from AWS API Gateway.

The client certificate for the API Gateway has been generated following the procedure suggested on the official AWS doc, which creates a PEM-formatted string.
link:   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html#generate-client-certificate

We would really appreciate if there is anyone that can list the correct steps that are required to install such certificate in the WSO2 keystores, including any potential change to configuration files (carbon.xml, axis2.xml, etc...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error you get? And in which server?

Comment: The response body states "Internal server error". The API GW log states "General SSLEngine problem". On the WSO2 AS side, no log is generated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is mutual SSL between the GW and AS. If yes, you can try this.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Enabling+Mutual+SSL

On a related note, if you haven't tried WSO2 API Manager, I suggest you try that too since you're already using WSO2 AS. It's a feature-rich API Management solution which you can customize as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank you! I don't use IS, does these instructions also apply to AS?

Comment: Yes, please try.

Comment: And thank you for your suggestion on WSO2 API Manager, I'll take into account this possibility

Comment: It seems it is not possible to import the WSO2 certificate into AWS API gateway. Also, how are we supposed to import a PEM formatted certificate into the WSO2 AS client-truststore.jks ?

Comment: 1 must be possible. For 2 read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35976_01/server.740/es_admin/src/tadm_ssl_convert_pem_to_jks.html

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with Amazon GW.